# Laravel - @section to @Yield troubles blade

Tags: laravel-5, yield, sections, laravel-blade

I have my master .php file setup here: views/layouts/app.blade.php
and my child here views/tasks.blade.php

In tasks.blade.php I wrote the following code:

```
  @extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
         [content here]
      </form>
    </div>
  @endsection
```

In app.blade.php I have a basic html setup with html-tags, bootstrap cdn, and jquery. In the body-tags I wrote:

```
@yield('content')
```

In routes.php the default route when localhost loads the map is set to 'tasks':

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('tasks');
});
```

However, I do not get the tasks.blade.php displayed within app.blade.php. this is what I DO get returned:

[image: console browser]

Any solutions please?

Comment: Looks fine to me from what you written and the code you’ve posted. Maybe check your error log?

Comment: There is definitely no problem here. What do you actually receive? Just tasks.blade.php? Where is the code where you are loading the view? Please edit the post with your route,

Comment: I reloaded my webserver and tried Safari instead of Chrome. Content gets displayed now. I suggest it might be a Chrome error?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you should have this

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
         [content here]
      </form>
    </div>
@stop
@stop
```